# Changing default button with Icon in Jquery DataTable is not working

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am using JQUERY DataTable. In that I am trying to change default button text with Icon. But except `copy` and `Print` other button icon is not changing. I am using `Font Awesome` To change text with icon. I have added `Font Awesome :` CDN also But its not appearing for `csv`, `excel`, `pdf` Why so? Am i missing any JQUERY references

**Font Awesome CDN**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />
```

**To Change Text with Icon**

```
initComplete: function () {
                            $('.buttons-copy').html('<i class="fa fa-copy" />')
                            $('.buttons-csv').html('<i class="fa fa-file-text-o" />')
                            $('.buttons-excel').html('<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" />')
                            $('.buttons-pdf').html('<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" />')
                            $('.buttons-print').html('<i class="fa fa-print" />')
                        },
```

**Complete JQuery DataTable**

```
function LoadTableData() {
            var params = {
                PlantCode: $('#ddlPlant').val(), CostCenterCode: $("[id$='ddlCostCenter']").val(),
                Status: $('input[name="Status"]:checked').val(), CompanyCode: $("[id$='ddlCompany']").val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'UserService.asmx/Get_Data_Cost_Center_Master',
                method: 'post',
                data: JSON.stringify(params),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function (data) {
                    $('#example').dataTable({
                        destroy: true,
                        data: data /*JSON.parse(data)*/,

                        columns: [
                            {
                                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                    return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                                }
                            },
                            { 'data': 'Cost_Center', class: 'editable text' },
                            { 'data': 'Plant', class: 'editable text' },
                            { 'data': 'Status', class: 'editable text' }

                        ],
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',

                        buttons: [
                            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                        ],
                        initComplete: function () {
                            $('.buttons-copy').html('<i class="fa fa-copy" />')
                            $('.buttons-csv').html('<i class="fa fa-file-text-o" />')
                            $('.buttons-excel').html('<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" />')
                            $('.buttons-pdf').html('<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" />')
                            $('.buttons-print').html('<i class="fa fa-print" />')
                        },
                        "searching": true,
                        "paging": true,
                        "info": true,
                        "language": {
                            "emptyTable": "No data available"
                        },
                        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
                            $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex + 1);
                            return nRow;
                        },
                    })
                },
                error: function (err) { // Added this event to capture the failed requests.
                    console.log(err.responseText);
                }
            });
        };
```

**Screenshot's**

[image]

Where i am going Wrong? Kindly help me

Comment: Nothing to do with datatables - your html for font icons isn't correct: https://jsfiddle.net/3b7r2ahg/

Comment: eg `file-text-o` doesn't exist - you probably `file-alt` https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&p=2&q=text

Comment: It looks like you're using classes from one version of font-awesome, but the css from another, eg for `fa-copy` it should be `fas fa-copy` not `fa fa-copy` (for fa 5.15.3 which is the css you're using) - pick a version and then review how to use it.